# Google action & Auth0 account linking Token expires for every 24hours

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I am developing a Google action and added account linking

In the linked image you can see the settings I did in Action console->Account linking.

[Action console Account linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFiM1.png)

In AuthO Applications added all fields necessary, JWT Expiration set to 604800 also in APIs setting I have updated Token Expiration (Seconds) to Token Expiration (Seconds)

[Auth0 application setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DehZ8.png)

[Auth0 api settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c32dU.png)

Account linking works perfectly but after 24 hours, my Google action prompts the user to ‘link the account again’, Even though I changed the JWT expiration to 7 days(604800 seconds) and Token Expiration to 7 days, I don’t know why action asks the user to link there account again after 24 hours. Is there anything I left out.

Kindly help me in this regard as it is very important me to publish action and running over my deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Assistant not accepting the long Access Token, the stranger thing is that it should be using a [Refresh Token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/refresh-tokens) to get a new Access Token instead of requiring the user to re-link the accounts.

Assuming you're using the auth token flow (and it looks like you are), Auth0 will send a Refresh Token [if you request the `offline_access` scope](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/get-refresh-tokens).

It looks like you're requesting `_offlineaccess`, which isn't the right scope. Changing this to the correct string (or adding it) should give the Assistant a Refresh Token, so it won't re-prompt the user unless the token is revoked.

Comment: thank you. I changed the scope from _offlineaccess to offline_access. It was my mistake, I will wait for the next 24 hrs and confirm

Comment: Glad it helped!